# Get Shuffled Tracks from Media Player

Tags: swift, media-player, apple-musickit

I want to get the queue from the Media Player. I believe that I can't read the queue though (is this correct?) and that I can only get the queue when I set it, like when I select a certain playlist to play. However I'm struggling to get the shuffled queue.

```
            let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
            let myMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songs()
            let predicateFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: chosenPlaylist, forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)
            myMediaQuery.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateFilter) as? Set<MPMediaPredicate>
            musicPlayerController.setQueue(with: myMediaQuery)
            musicPlayerController.repeatMode = .all
            musicPlayerController.shuffleMode = .songs
            musicPlayerController.play()
            for track in myMediaQuery.items! {
                print(track.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)!)
            } // here I don't get the shuffled order that is going to play, just get the original order of the playlist
```

I need the shuffled as I want to be able to display what's going to play next.

Comment: The MPMusicPlayerController queue allows itself to be set, but not accessed. You can loop through the mediaItemCollection in mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection), then add each item to an array of MPMediaItem, then use it to display the next song. I think shuffling only impacts play order, not the actual queue - you may have to capture the mediaItemCollection, assign it to a variable, randomize it, then set the queue using that randomized variable, and keep shuffle actually turned off so you know the 'random' order.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll have to shuffle myself and just capture the shuffle then, but if I can use the .shufflemode option that would be preferable

Comment: Agreed, MPMusicPlayerController is tricky to work with. Best of luck, I hope it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had trouble with `.shuffleMode` in the past. Call `shuffled()` on the collection instead:

```
// shuffle
func shufflePlaylist() {

    let query = MPMediaQuery.songs()
    let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "Art Conspiracy",
                                             forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName,
                                             comparisonType: .equalTo)
    query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)

    guard let items = query.items else { return }
    let collection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: items.shuffled())

    player.setQueue(with: collection)
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Another silly workaround we have to do, because of the arbitrary things Apple makes available in MediaKit, but that's great! Cheers

Comment: Yeah. I stumbled across the issue in a previous version of Xcode, which was in beta at the time. I figured it was due to 'beta stuff' and would be fixed later, but it wasn't. So, I tried shuffling the collection itself, and voilà. Glad it was helpful.

Comment: This works fine for small arrays (few hundred songs). I'm trying to shuffle my entire library (19000 songs) and setting the queue by creating an MPMediaItemCollection like this takes about 5-6 seconds. Setting directly by MPMediaQuery is about 1 second.